# Populating a dropdown list in Flash Builder

Tags: drop-down-menu, flash-builder

I'm currently using the following code in Flash Builder to return a list of variables from an XML file:

```
[Bindable] private var I_Authors:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection (); 

            private function init():void {
                var param:Object = new Object();
                param.action = "getAuthorXML";
                authorService.send(param);
            }

protected function authorService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                I_Authors = event.result.authors.author;
            }
```

My problem is making use of this data in a dropdown list.

I have no trouble putting it into a data grid using `dataProvider="{I_Authors}"` and `dataField="ID"` etc., but all the attempts I've made to put a specific field (ID) into a dropdown list have resulted in "object Object".

I'm just starting out with flash builder so its probably a basic question but all of the tutorials I've followed on Adobe's website don't seem to be any help.

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you use `labelField=""` , just incase anyone else is a bit confused about this.

```
<s:DropDownList id="dropdownList" dataProvider="{________}" labelField="________"></s:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "author" is an object.

When you get your results from authorService you receive an object

I_Authors = event.result.authors.author;

So you have an array of objects.

You probably want to get property of your object eg.: author.ID

I_Authors = event.result.authors.author.ID;

So you have an array of author ID.

dataProvider= I_Authors

Let me know if it wasn't clear and you need more explanation.